# $A$ is in $\Theta (n \log n)$ and $B$ is in $\Theta (2^n)$ - $B$ can not be more efficient than $A$?

Tags: asymptotics

Now suppose that $A$ is in $\Theta (n \log (n))$ and $B$ is in $\Theta (2^n)$. Is it always possible that $B$ is more efficient (asymptotically) than $A$? I think the answer is no, but I am not sure how to prove it. Can you help me at this point? One is bounded by there $n\log(n)$ and the other is bounded by $2^n$.

For me $f(n) \in \Theta (g(n))$ means that $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = c > 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me rephrase your question slightly in the way I understand it:

Given two functions $f(n) \in \Theta(n\log n)$ and $g(n) \in \Theta(2^n)$, is it always true that $f(n)\in o(g(n))$?

Then the answer is yes, as $n\log n \in o(2^n)$. More precisely, you know by definition that there are positive constants $c$ and $k$ such that for large enough $n$, $f(n)\leq cn\log n$ and $g(n)\geq k2^n$. So, for large enough $n$, you have $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \leq \frac{cn\log n}{k2^n}\to 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. Thus, $f(n)\in o(g(n))$.

Comment: Can you modify you answer according to my definition of theta?

Comment: @Leo Did you mean to have a limit of $c>0$ rather than an equality in the definition you added? As it stands your definition is much too restrictive to be of any use, plus it implies $f(n)\in \Theta(-f(n))$ for any fonction with no zero.

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: It is because I did  not have used your notation so far. If you have time, I would appreciate a lot. I will accept your answer if you can tweak it.